# How to add an array of objects to a mongoose database which has more than one documents in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am passing axios request to the backend , in order words, `req.body` is passing an array of objects here `newItemsObj` I am trying to save these array of objects into the mongoose database with the schema `NewItemsData` this data model is referencing another data model `MoneyInData` but while trying to save to the NewItemsData model I get a `ValidationError` that several fields are required, please what could I be doing wrong and how can I save this array of Objects effectively in the database. The codes here are just snippets to make it quite easy to understand.

Please I will need your help thank you.

```
//NewItemsData Model

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MoneyInData = require('./MoneyInData');

const newItemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    productName:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    sellingPriceOfTotal:{
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    quantityCount: {
        type: Number
    },
    unitOfQuantity:{
        type: String
    },
    sellingPrice:{
        type: Number,
        required:true
    },
    sales:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'MoneyInData'
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('NewItemsData', newItemsSchema);

//MoneyInData Model

const mongoose = require ('mongoose')

const moneyInDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    totalAmountIn:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    amountRecieved:{
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    balanceDue: {
        type: Number
    },
    itemDescription:{
        type: String
    },
    modeOfPayment:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    }

})
module.exports = mongoose.model('MoneyInData', moneyInDataSchema)

//Create Method for Writing to the database

// @desc post newItems 
// @route POST /newItems
// @access Private
const createNewItems = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

    const  newItemsObj  = req.body
    console.log(newItemsObj)
    if (!newItemsObj) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'All fields are required' })
    }
    const addNewItems = await NewItemsData.create(newItemsObj);

    if (addNewItems) {//created
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'New Item Recorded' })
        console.log(addNewItems)
        console.log(newItemsObj)
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid Item' })
    }
})


//sample array of Object data contained in newItemsObj variable
{
  newItemApiList: [
    {
      productName: 'molly',
      sellingPriceOfTotal: 17400,
      quantityCount: 3,
      unitOfQuantity: 'grams',
      sellingPrice: '5800'
    },
    {
      productName: 'group',
      sellingPriceOfTotal: 9000,
      quantityCount: 2,
      unitOfQuantity: 'cm',
      sellingPrice: '4500'
    }
  ]
}

//Error message:
ValidationError: NewItemsData validation failed: sellingPrice: Path `sellingPrice` is required., sellingPriceOfTotal: Path `sellingPriceOfTotal` is required., productName: Path `productName` is required.
    at Document.invalidate (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\business-books\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3183:32)
    at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\business-books\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2976:17
    at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\business-books\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1368:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
GET/newItems
GET/newItems
```

Comment: schema key which has `required : true` element that value must be pass when you insert data.

Comment: Yea, I have tried removing the required keyword but when I do that, only the auto generated object id shows up in the database

Comment: i think you must have to use insertMany to add multiple document.

Comment: Okay, I have done that too, still having that issue, i.e only the auto generated object id shows up in database

Comment: The [Model.create()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.create()) methods accepts an object or an array of objects if creating more than one document. Please post either your front-end code that submits your post request or the output of `console.log(newItemsObj)` from your `createNewItems` function so that I can see it's structure. It's likely the array has been sent as a value to an object property and you need to access it that way or use spread syntax instead of just dumping the `newItemsObj` in the `Model.create` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `newItemApiList` is the array then try:

```js
const addNewItems = await NewItemsData.create(newItemsObj.newItemApiList);
```

or using spread syntax if you prefer

```js
const addNewItems = await NewItemsData.create([...newItemsObj.newItemApiList]);
```

Comment: WOW!! that was supper smooth, worked like magic, thanks so much @jQueeny, saved my time.

Comment: @Aham_Uzoma you're welcome.